# How to write the javascript function calling the asp.net button click() event in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am writting the javascript function like this

```
 function PreviewImg(imgFile, labelid,frameid) {
labelid.innerHTML = imgFile.value;
document.getElementById('btnupload').click();
}
```

Above code  **document.getElementById('btnupload').click();** is the error but firefox browser is supported but i have support IE8 , pls give me suggestion
error is `htmlfile: Access is denied.`

Comment: use JQuery for fuly cross-browser javascript !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one also works for me.

document.getElementById('ctl00_btnupload').click();

but you can test it by yourself. Good luck..

Comment: try this one:
document.getElementById('<%=btnUpload.clientID%>').click().
may be this one working.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnupload.ClientID %>').click();
```